No puedo guardar los datos en mi base de datos Mysql
Mi problema es que, si bien la conexion a la base de datos esta bien (ya corrobore que se conecte) pero a la hora de completar los datos en mi formulario de HTML y le doy al boton de enviar, la pagina me recarga y me tira error... cuando voy a chequear si los datos ingresados en el formulario, fueron enviados a mi tabla de sql (estoy usando apache y mysql, con Xampp) no me registro nada! Dejo a continuacion el codigo HTML y luego el de PHP
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>INDEX</title>
</head>

<body>

  <H1>Formulario de REGISTRO</H1>

  <h2> Complete los Datos</h2>

  <form method="post" action="../Base de Datos/registroV1.php">
    <section class="registro">
      <input class="campo" type="text" title="nombre" required name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre">
      <input class="campo" type="text" title="apellido" required name="apellido" placeholder="Escriba su Apellido">
      <input class="campo" type="email" title="email" required name="email" placeholder="Escriba su email">
      <input class="campo" type="password" title="password" required name="password" placeholder="Escriba su clave">
      <input class="enviar" type="submit" value="enviar" name="boton">
      <p class="cuenta-existente">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="../inicio.html">Inicia sesión aquí</a></p>
      </section>
      
  

  </form>

   

      </body>

      </html>

PHP
 <?php

//declaracion de variables
$dbhost = "localhost" ;
$dbUsername = "root" ;
$dbPassword = "" ;
$dbName = "registro" ;

//conexion a la base de datos
$conexion = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

//para comprobar la conexion con la base de datos
if($conexion->connect_errno) {
    die("Conexion fallida: " . $conexion->connect_errno);
}
else {
    echo "Conexion Exitosa";
}


if (isset ($_POST["send"])) {
    
     if (
        strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST["lastname"]) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST["email"]) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST["password"]) >= 1 

     ) {
        $nombre = trim($_POST["nombre"]);
        $apellido = trim($_POST["apellido"]);
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        $clave = trim($_POST["clave"]);
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO tabla_2(nombre, apellido, email, clave)
                     VALUES (`$nombre`, `$apellido`, `$email`, `$clave` )";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?>
               <h3 class="ok"> Se han completado los datos correctamente </h3>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
               <h3 class="ok"> Ups ah ocurrido un herror! </h3>
            <?php 
        }

     }else {
        ?>
        <h3 class="ok"> Complete todos los datos! </h3>
     <?php
     }

}
?>

Una vez que le doy a enviar me lleva a una pagina con error. No se si es un problema de codigo o es algo externo...

y cual es el error que sale???

Esta página no funciona
Si el problema persiste, comunícate con el propietario del sitio.
HTTP ERROR 405
El tipico error de cuando no funcionan las paginas. Perdon soy nuevo en esto!!

y ya hablaste con el propietario del sitio ???

Lo soy yo jajaja

Saludos. Te sugiero en lugar del <h3 class="ok"> Ups ah ocurrido un herror! </h3>, dentro del h3 coloques el llamado a mysqli_error para que te indique la descripción (en lo posible) de lo que ocurre (si es error) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

@RobertoLeOr eso no funciona si hay suprecion de errores ya que el mysqli_error generar un exception controlado no visible ... lo que se ocupa es que el SR en el entorno de desarrollo habilite los errores en php ... y/o averigue donde esta su log de errores del php del servidor y publicque aqui el error que se registro ...

Uno de los problemas que puedes estar teniendo es en la consulta a la base de datos. El uso de las comillas escapadas (`) pueden generar problemas. La solución que propongo es que lo cambies por esto:
$consulta = "INSERT INTO tabla_2 (nombre, apellido, email, clave) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$clave')";

Así debería funcionar la consulta.
Luego por otra parte tenemos un problema en esta linea de PHP:
if (isset ($_POST["send"]))

En nuestro caso como al botón le has dado el name="boton" este valor de name es lo que se manda al POST, por lo que cuando buscas en la variable $_POST para conseguir el valor que nos esta pasando este formulario hay que buscarlo por el valor que le has asignado:
if (isset ($_POST["boton"]))

Luego por último falta comprobar que la url donde estás mandando la info del post sea correcta en el action.
No se que tipo de arquitectura estarás empleando para el proyecto pero esta ruta que tu pones me resulta un poco extraña action="../Base de Datos/registroV1.php", habitualmente se lanza a la misma URL de la pagina en cuestión, por ejemplo: action="registroV1.php"
Espero que te sirva!
Un saludo.

Muchas Gracias! si me sirvió!!!
